# iPhone vibration while playing audio

Tags: iphone, audio, vibration

My application plays audio using AudioQueue and AudioSession. I can't stop playing according to application workflow. Currently, my customer ask me to perform iPhone vibration according to some conditions. I've tried to perform it with AudioServices playing vibration as system sound or alert sound. There is not positive result. Could somebody help me and tell how to implement it? I'm making legal application for non jailbreaked iPhones and can't use custom freamworks because Apple can reject application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using this solution :)

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;         
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error:&err];         
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  error:&err];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get the vibration:

`#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;         
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error:&err];         
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I've made same. But now I use PlayAndRecord category because I need to simulate microphone recording to show double-height status bar. I think that problem with category. :(

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I'm not using `AudioQueue` but an `AVAudioEngine` to record something, and for my case I pinpointed it down to having to pause the input in order to play the vibration properly with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` during a record session.

So in my case, I did something like this

```
audioEngine?.pause()
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519)
do {
  try audioEngine.start()
} catch let error {
  print("An error occurred starting audio engine. \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```